# recursively cut a list into defaultdict tree leaves

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've seen this here and elsewhere:

```
import collections

def Tree():
    return collections.defaultdict(Tree)
```

I want to place values into that tree such that values are grouped so

```
some_func(my_tree[0])
```

might be written to return my_tree[0][0] + my_tree[0][1]

This works:

```
def subdivision_tree(pts):
    retval = Tree()
    def branch(pts, tree, keys=[0]):
        assert pts, "empty list sent to branch in subdivision_tree"
        if len(pts) == 1:
            for key in keys[:-1]:
                tree = tree[key]
            tree[keys[-1]] = pts[0]
        else:
            c = len(pts)//2
            branch(pts[:c], tree, keys=keys+[0])
            branch(pts[c:], tree, keys=keys+[1])
    branch(pts, retval)
    return retval

> subdivision_tree(list(range(5)))
"something like"
... {
...  0:
...      {
...       0:
...           {
...            0: 0,
...            1: 1
...           },
...       1:
...           {
...            0: 2,
...            1:
...                {
...                 0: 3,
...                 1: 4
...                }
...           }
...      }
... }
```

But I think I'm missing something obvious. Is there a clearer way to accomplish this?

Comment: You might want to look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bintrees/2.0.1 (Have no experience using it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A smarter way to go about this:

```
def branch(list_):
    if len(list_) == 1:
        return list_[0]
    else:
        return {
            0: branch(list_[:1]),
            1: branch(list_[1:])}
```

- returns a simpler dictionary
  (that can still be regrouped by `some_func(dict_[0]) ==> dict_[0][0] + dict[0][1]`)
- clearer
- fwiw, more elegant.
- more Pythonic?